# Memory segmentation, heap and mmap

Tags: linux, memory, x86, memory-segmentation

This question is mainly relevant for x86, and linux

on x86 every operation that accesses the memory needs to be done from within some "segment" when executing your program your program holds three segment registers pointing to some memory addresses e.g

- you have `CS` which points to some memory where within it you could
  read and execute
- you have `DS` which points to some memory where within it you could
  read and write
- and you have `SS` which points to some memory where within it you
  could also read and write

when executing some code, every `JMP` or `CALL` instruction you make to some address would be checked by your processor to be within your `CS`, every read/write operatin you make on global variables within your code would be checked by the CPU if within your `DS` memory limits, and so regarding the `SS`, 
given this, we are provided with some memory model that provides memory protection.

now my question is, what happens when we dynamically allocate some memory?
or memory map it?, 
it's not enough for the OS to allocate me with some memory, executing program must have some register pointing to the place where the IO operations are made... I'm assuming that this is where the FS / GS / ES registers kick in yet I'm not sure absolutely. I'd like it if someone here with more experience within this field could explain this to me...

I've wrote some code testing this earlier and disassembled it, and the output was disappointing..

my code was something like

```
int main()
{
 int * mem = (int *) malloc(4096)

 mem[0] = 5;

 return 0;
}
```

and I've expected to see within the disassembled code something like

```
lea eax, mem_addr
mov fs:[eax], 5
```

yet that didn't happen.. I'd love it if someone could clear this to me

Comment: 1) The allocated memory has just to be within a segment of your, there is no need to use a new segment 2) All programs use the same segments, that happen to be the greatest possible segments 3) segmentation has stopped being used long time ago, such long that x64 has mostly removed it 4) Paging is used for isolation instead

Comment: And what did you see?  It's also disappointing to read half the story, so please add what you saw in the assembler listing.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

I interpreted your question in two ways, the first one asking how the memory management is done on a modern OS; and the second one as how the memory management *was* done in a segmented architecture.

The first part is very wide, so I'll just focus on the minimal background to support the conclusion.

The second part, was just a curiosity of mine and I seized the opportunity to write something about it.

---

As far as I know, Linux never actually supported a segmented memory model<sup>1</sup>, relying instead on paging.

[image: Segmentation vs Paging]

In the paged model, every program uses the same set of segments for code, data and stack. These segments are made as big as the whole address space; making the transformation from a *logical address* to a *linear address* an identity map, effectively disabling segmentation<sup>2</sup>.
In the picture above, the red and blue programs are isolated either by: A) Using different segments, as in the left B) Using different pages, as in the right.

Note that in the paged model, from a *linear address* range perspective, both process occupy the *same* range, they overlap.
It is the paging step that map the same *linear address* into a *different physical address* depending on the process.

Linux uses a paged model, segmentation is barely used and that why you won't see any selector register (like `fs`) being loaded before a memory access.
Also `malloc`, for 32 bits systems, returns a 32 bits value and not a 48 bits one (16 for the selector, 32 for the offset).

One reason behind the choice of neglecting the segmentation mechanism is, indeed, that memory management in such architecture is overly complex and inefficient.

Since on a Linux machine a program is not limited by any artificial segment limit:

- There is no need to use a different segment to access an allocated buffer, in practical terms this means that pointers are always near<sup>3</sup>.
- There is no need to move, grow or shrink a segment, instead of relying on far pointers an OS can be optimistic and grow/shrink a segment, if possible, or move it entirely.
- The allocated memory doesn't need to be continuous.

In fact allocation is just a matter of finding a free page (or more than one) and map it for the demanding process.

[image: Page allocation]

In the picture above the red process just requested a page of memory, the yellow one.

Paging is a topic on its own, but that's the main concept.
`mmap`ing is the same as allocating but the pages are not backed by the swap space, instead they are backed by a specific file<sup>4</sup>.

---

### Allocating memory on a segmented model

This section address the second interpretation of your question.
Or it is just informative.

When actually constrained to work on a segmented architecture a program, and an OS too, is forced to deal with segmentation.

The main problems with segmentation are:

1. The segment is smaller than the whole address space, thereby the program may run out of space despite the fact that most of the computer memory is free.
2. Data larger than the segment size is problematic to handle.
3. Switching segments is expensive from an hardware point of view, since specific loads must be interleaved to normal instructions, and from a compiler point of view, since correct "segment tracking" must be implemented.
4. There could be aliasing, three different data sitting in three different segments could happen to be accessible within just one segment.

The simplest way to abstract segmentation is to always use far pointers.
Every access is done with a far pointer.
Even with the obvious optimizations this was extremely expensive since: A) most program didn't required much memory B) Pointers double their size C) Segment registers must be loaded before any access.

So the programmer was not totally abstracted from segmentation, they had to declare how they intended to use the memory.
This gave rise to the various memory models:

- *Tiny*. Data, code and stack on the same segment. All pointers are near.
- *Small*. Code on its own, data and stack on the same segment. All pointers are near.
- *Compact*. Code on its own, data and stack on multiple segments. Code pointers<sup>5</sup> are near, data and stack pointers are far.
- *Medium*. Code on multiple segments, data and stack on a single segment. Code pointers are far, segment and data are near.
- *Large*. Code, stack and data are on multiple segments. Every pointer is far.
- *Huge*. Like *Compact* but a single data element, for example an array, can span multiple segments.
- *Flat*. As described in the first section.

Depending on the declared mode, a compiler used the proper pointer type.
Your example when compiled in a *compact* or *large* model should give the result you were expecting.

The way the memory is allocated depend on what kind of allocation is requested, either near or far.
For a far allocation an OS must find a free segment, mark it as busy and return a far pointer to it.
If more than a segment need to be allocated, the OS can use various mechanisms: A) Allocated consecutive segments B) Return an handle instead and have another function to get a pointer to a window in the allocated area C) Deny it, force the program to make multiple calls and relinquish to it the burden of hiding this to the programmer.

If the segments have fixed size, allocating a local, i.e. near, buffer was technically superfluous, the segment is already all allocated.
A call to `malloc` were resolved entirely by the C run-time, that kept an heap<sup>6</sup> of the memory allocated in the segment.

If the segments can grow and shrink, allocating a local buffer can be trickier, for example a segment can be kept just as large as it necessary and grown on request.
Eventually it could even be moved, since all near pointer are relative from its starting.

Two interesting, historical, windows on the problem of allocating memory on a segmented architecture:

- [What was the difference between LocalAlloc and GlobalAlloc?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041101-00/?p=37433). Where `LocalAlloc` and `GlobalAlloc` reflect the near vs far and heap management aspects of the problem.
- [Using Large Arrays In Turbo C](http://www.drdobbs.com/using-large-arrays-in-turbo-c/184402289). Where the issues a programmer was forced to face are highlighted with practical examples.

---

<sup>1</sup> It requires a 386+.
<sup>2</sup> As it actually *is* in x86_64.
<sup>3</sup> Except maybe for TLS, but the selector is implied and fixed so they are not really true far pointers.
<sup>4</sup> Unless anonymous.
<sup>5</sup> Including code targets for `jmp`, `call`, ...
<sup>6</sup> Yes, *that* heap.

Comment: Hey margaret, firstly thank you for the lovely explanation!!!!!!!!!, yet there are still something I've misunderstood, In my original question, when referring to segmentation, I've meant using **segment tables in a paged memory model**, I know segment models are no longer used... yet segment registers are still used in order to provide protection levels and memory protection, segments selectors are STILL in use in x86-64 but only to provide protection rings within executed programs.. so when using mmap on some memory in order to execute code, would the GDT be changed?

Comment: that's what I mean, I refer to segments registers as holders of descriptors, pointers to the GDT.. I know segmentation model isn't used since x386 was introduced, anyways thank you very much this is a great explanation

Comment: @some_random_guy_iam The selectors are still used to provide protection, but *segmentation* is mostly disabled on x86_64. Why do you think `mmap` would change the GDT to map executable pages?

Comment: Fun fact: a couple early Linux no-execute security hardening implementation (for x86 hardware that doesn't support the per-page NX bit) used segment tricks (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_space_protection#Exec_Shield).  I've never been curious enough about x86 segmentation to try to grok it, but this is sort of an exception to the otherwise-accurate statement that Linux only uses paging, not segmentation (although still with a flat memory model).  I don't think any of those patches were ever part of the main-line Linux tree, though.

Comment: @MargaretBloom well the GDT defines segments withn memory that have permission protections upon them... when if suddenly that segment size would've been needed to be expanded?

Comment: @some_random_guy_iam That would be a pain in the back, to expand a segment. That's why everyone prefers to have full length segments. Note that segments are used to give a program its CPL, it is still paging the set what is accessible to whom. From a GDT pov a program has access to the whole memory.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Are you sure? segments still limit you to some size, if i'd try executing some code in a data segment when writing some C program I would definitely encounter some segfault

Comment: @some_random_guy_iam That's because of *NXE* bit. Try compiling [this program](http://pastebin.com/4mwujAqx) as indicated in its top comment.